# Mongodb c# include sub properties in result in order to map to result class

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following code working:

```
var Logs = MvcApplication.MongoLoggingDatabase.GetCollection<Log>("Log")
            .Find(queryDocument)
            .Select(x => new LogDto { ModelNumber = x.Request.ModelNumber, Make = x.Request.Make, TimeStamp = x.TimeStamp, UserId = x.UserId })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp)
            .Skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
            .Take(pageSize);
```

I am ablde to map the results into LogDto.  But I am wondering if I can use FindAs instead, so that I can just query the fields I want and map the cooresponding sub properties as expected.

I tried something like the following:

```
var Logs = MvcApplication.MongoLoggingDatabase.GetCollection<Log>("Log")
                .FindAs<LogDto>(queryDocument)
                .SetFields(Fields.Exclude("_id").Include("TimeStamp", "UserId", "Request_ModelNumber", "Request_Make"))
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp)
                .Skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
                .Take(pageSize);
```

TimeStamp and UserId are mapped correctly, but Make and ModelNumber only show null.  I would like to know how to map Request.ModelNumber and Request.Make to the corresponding fields (Make and Model) on LogDto using SetFields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't do it. SetFields can be used to select which fields are returned, but it can't be used to reshape the returned document. All the values needed to deserialize a LogDto have to come from the same level of the BSON document (not some of them nested inside a Request like ModelNumber and Make are).

You either have to make your class match the document format or change your document format to match your class.